# React-native sticking the image to the bottom

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to make the image sticking to the bottom of the app. How can I do it ? I have tried different stack overflow solutions but I still cannot get the result. As you can see there is a large white space between the red border and the image. The image is trim and there should be no extra space under it. Thanks in advance !

```
 const TubeBoard = () =>
  (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={bigTube}
        style={styles.imageStyle}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    </View>
  );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceHeight,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
  },
});
```

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbOGA.png)

**Solved** : Get the desired result by adding { flex: 1 } to container, and height to the image.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderWidth: 10,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceHeight * 0.75,
  },
});
```

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GLLd.png)

Comment: Try putting after a scroll view

Comment: try to wrap `image` in a `View` and move the `position:absolute` to the `View` stylist

Comment: @gaback tried but still can't get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the desired result by adding { flex: 1 } to container, and height to the image.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderWidth: 10,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceHeight * 0.75,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your container view is not filling the entire screen. 
Try adding `flex:1` to your container style.

Answer (score 0):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...
  },
  imageStyle: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 10,
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: 100
  },
});
```